# Creating a new instance of a class from another class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, hashset

So I'm stuck on some homework trying to create an instance of the Employee class from my class called records.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>

{
/* instance variables */
private String Name;
private String employeeNumber;


/**
 * Constructor for Employee
 */
public Employee(String employNum)
{
   super();
   this.employeeNumber = employNum;             
}
```

Next I need to create a Record class that will create a HashSet of Employees details, this is where I need help.

```
public class Records
{
   private HashSet employeeSet;

   public Records()
   {
      Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
   }
```

Then I want it to have a method for adding a new employee and then putting their records in the set.

```
   public  enrollEmployee(String num)
   {
      Employee newEmp = new Employee(num);
      employeeSet.add(newEmp);
   }
}
```

I can't get that last bit to create a new employee, it doesn't come out with an error and it compiles correctly. Just no new employee. 
*Adding the employeeSet.add(newEmp); caused a compiler warning and that method won't run due to a NullPointerException, probably because the employee isn't actually created.

For more info, when I create an employee the name should come out as "null" if only an employee number is entered but I still need to store that information.

Edited to update information. There is more detail for the Employee class which I have left out, I'm only supposed to be creating the Records class.

Last update, thank you for the help. After reading the replies this is what I got to work for me.

```
   public class Records
{
   private Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();

   public Records()
   {

   }

   public void enrollEmployee(String num)
   {
      Employee newEmp = new Employee(num);
      employeeSet.add(newEmp);
   }
}
```

Comment: _"I can't get that last bit to create a new employee."_. Are you getting an error? what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Your ```Set<String>``` should probably be a ```Set<Employee>``` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres the new solution based on what you are looking for in the comments

```
public class Record
  {
    private Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();

    public Record()
    {
        newEmployee("1");
        newEmployee("2");
        newEmployee("3");
    }

    public void newEmployee(String employNumber)
    {
        Employee newEmp = new Employee(employNumber);
        employeeSet.add(newEmp);
    }
 }
```

The method that you created was never called on... So an employee was never created. Therefore, by calling on the newEmployee method in the Record Constructor, a new employee is created

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed the set creation, I had actually just come out with that as well. The main problem I'm having is that code just doesn't create a new employee.

I can't change the Employee class, I'm only supposed to create the new  Records class. There is a lot more details in it I didn't include such as for the compareTo.

Comment: Than create an employee when you instantiate records through the constructor// I changed my solution based on what you are telling me